# RCP application crashes when link in intro is clicked

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Currently I'm building an XHTML-Intro using CustomizableIntroPart. I implemented a search field with auto comoletion using jQuery on this page. Whenever I try to click on a search result that calls a http://org.eclipse.ui.intro/runAction?... URL everything is fine. But when I open that link using the return or enter button on the keyboard the whole JVM crashes with the following message:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x5c8bb6f2, pid=7580, tid=8816
#
# JRE version: 7.0_05-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.1-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ieframe.dll+0x13b6f2]  Ordinal159+0xcee3
```

I tried debugging the error and landed somewhere in the class org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject in the method callback2

I'm using eclipse 3.7.2, JDK 7u5 and Win7 64 Bit

Anyone facing similar problems?

Comment: I'd recommend submitting this (and your workaround) as a bug to Eclipse - especially if it's something that can crash the JVM like that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is related to threading. Inside the called org.eclipse.ui.intro.config.IIntroAction I hid the intro and opened an editor. Opening the editor asynchronously solves the problem:

```
Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(createOpenEditorRunnable());
```

Hope this is of use to somebody.